# Using MKDirections to get Map Directions and Routes not working

Tags: ios, swift, maps

i am trying to provide the user with a navigation direction with the click of a button. But for some reason it doesn't seem to be working.

```
@IBAction func directionToDestination(sender: AnyObject) {
        getDirections()
    }

    func getDirections(){
        let request = MKDirectionsRequest()
        let destination = MKPlacemark(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(place.latitude, place.longitude), addressDictionary: nil)
        request.setSource(MKMapItem.mapItemForCurrentLocation())
        request.setDestination(MKMapItem(placemark: destination))
        request.transportType = MKDirectionsTransportType.Automobile
        var directions = MKDirections(request: request)
        directions.calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler({(response:
            MKDirectionsResponse!, error: NSError!) in

            if error != nil {
                // Handle error
            } else {
                self.showRoute(response)
            }

        })
    }

        func showRoute(response: MKDirectionsResponse) {

           for route in response.routes as! [MKRoute] {

                placeMap.addOverlay(route.polyline,level: MKOverlayLevel.AboveRoads)
                for step in route.steps {
                    println(step.instructions)
                }
            }
    }

            func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, rendererForOverlay
                overlay: MKOverlay!) -> MKOverlayRenderer! {
                    let renderer = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay)

                    renderer.strokeColor = UIColor.blueColor()
                    renderer.lineWidth = 5.0
                    return renderer
            }
```

here is how my `viewDidLoad()` looks

```
manager = CLLocationManager()
        manager.delegate = self
        manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        placeMap.delegate = self
```

**can someone please point what am i doing wrong with a sample code in swift ?**

Answer (score 1):

Here is a full working sample for getting the users location and getting directions to a destination coordinate.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    mapView.showsUserLocation = true
    mapView.delegate = self
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}

@IBAction func directionToDestinationButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    guard let userLocationCoordinate = UserLocation.shared.location?.coordinate else { return }
    let directionRequest = MKDirections.Request()
    directionRequest.source = MKMapItem(
        placemark: MKPlacemark(
            coordinate: userLocationCoordinate
        )
    )
    directionRequest.destination = MKMapItem(
        placemark: MKPlacemark(
            coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 47.6205, longitude: -122.3493)
        )
    )
    directionRequest.transportType = .automobile
    let directions = MKDirections(request: directionRequest)
    directions.calculate { (response, error) in
        guard let response = response else { return }
        let route = response.routes.first
        if let line = route?.polyline {
            self.mapView.addOverlay(line, level: .aboveRoads)
        }
    }
}


//MARK: - MKMapViewDelegate
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
    if let polyLine = overlay as? MKPolyline {
        let lineRenderer = MKPolylineRenderer(polyline: polyLine)
        lineRenderer.strokeColor = .red
        lineRenderer.lineWidth = 3
        return lineRenderer
    }
    
    return MKOverlayRenderer()
}

//MARK: - CLLocationManagerDelegate
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    UserLocation.shared.location = locations.first
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    switch status {
    case .authorizedWhenInUse:
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        locationManager.startUpdatingHeading()
    case .denied:
        UserLocation.shared.location = nil
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    case .notDetermined:
        UserLocation.shared.location = nil
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    default:
        break
    }
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
    print("Location Manager Error -> \(String(describing: error.localizedDescription))")
}
}
```

Add this class to hold the users location

```
class UserLocation {
    static let shared = UserLocation()
    var location: CLLocation?
}
```

In the Info.plist add this key and value

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Location Usage Description Shown To The User</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you added the two required strings into the plist project.

```
 NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription
 NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription
```

Comment: so when you ran the code ... do you have any errors?

Comment: no errors. It just doesn't do anything. I have my map already showing the users current location. But when i click on the directions button it doesn't do anything

Comment: but wait if you looking for to create a route you need a starting location either your  hard coded them the destination coordinates in the code and set the current location into the simulator

Comment: i am using users current location as the source and provided the same to the simulator

Comment: Did you try to reset the simulator?... and also when you first ran the app did it ask you to allow  get access to the GPS

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87103/discussion-between-lamar-and-sumesh).